# Can there be two stand-alone application profile in one node?

Tags: websphere

I've installed WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment and need to run three different applications.

For each (Standalone) Application Profile creation I come across these options
Node Name, Server Name & Host name.

When first profile is created the values are
Node name - iamNode01
Server name - server1
Host name - iam

Second profile has following values auto-populated
Node name - iamNode02
Server name - server1
Host name - iam

etc..

If any one could help me understand on Node name and server name part.

Comment: Did you really intend for this "extreme" level of isolation? You don't need three servers, much less three standalone servers, just to run three different applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of profile, you can have a single server/standalone profile, or one that is part of a cell and managed by a deployment manager. If you are using standalone profiles I would recommend having one server per profile. If you are using a deployment manager managed profile then you can have multiple servers per profile.

Comment: If am using standalone profile is it possible to deploy more than one application on single standalone profile?

So far I was under assumption that after installing WAS ND core product files If we want to deploy one application, a standalone profile should be created and application will be deployed on it. Subsequently if another application needs to be deployed another standalone profile would be created and application would be deployed on the second standalone profile.

Comment: You can install multiple applications into a server in a standalone profile. Some choose not to do this because they want better isolation between applications. It is a choice between more isolation between applications vs essentially fewer resources used.

Comment: We recommend a standalone profile to server ratio of 1:1. We make no similar recommendation about server to application ratios. That decision would be specific to your environment and applications.

Comment: Note: Request you to ignore best practise for a while as am digging deep for understanding.

So I can either install second application also on server1 of Standalone profile AppSrv01 and this what you mean by server to application ratio. Correct? A standalone profile to server ratio of 1:1 is recommended. Is it also possible to have another server name server2 on profile AppSrv01 and have second application installed?  If yes, I would like to know how can server2 be created on AppSrv01?

Comment: These all seems like things you could try hands-on pretty trivially ,rather than badgering the people who are trying to help by providing answers.

Answer (score 1):

When an ND installation spans more than one machine, each machine has to be a different node.  You can have multiple nodes on a single machine too if you like.

If there's a deployment manager in use, the simplest single machine setup is two profiles, one with the deployment manager in it and the other with all the appservers in it.

If there's no deployment manager (a standalone profile), then the simplest thing is one appserver per profile, and each profile will have it's own nodename.

Answer (score 0):

Node name usually identifies logical node, in case of distributed installations (the ones with deployment manager), it helps you identify machine where servers are installed.

In case of standalone profiles, it is just hostname with Node0# appended.
If you want to have multiple standalone profiles on one machine, you can consider creating AdminAgent profile and register standalone profiles there. It will allow you to administer all servers from one console, just selecting specific profile on login.

You could create many servers on single standalone profile, however it is only possible via wsadmin and in general not recommended.

Server name identifies specific JVM, it must be unique on given node.

Comment: @Mihir Here [Creating a server using scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_createserver.html?lang=en). You can have many applications on single server like `server1`, or you can have them on different servers. Probably you could have several standalone profiles with same node name, but if you would ever like to connect them to deployment manager or job manager, that would not be possible. So it is recommended to have different node names.

Comment: Useful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an element you are missing here is that Standalone profiles are not coordinated by a deployment manager nor node agent, so they are each just acting as if they are the a singler server on a single node -- hence the apparent duplication/multiple nodes per host.

You wouldn't have this relationship in federated (non-standalone) profiles -- just 1 managed node per operating system instance.